# Migrated from HTTP to HTTPS and my wordpress site is requesting Google Font stylesheets over HTTP?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, https

I've done this a few times with no issues. I replaced all references to HTTP scripts with HTTPS requests, deactivated plugins one-by-one, and scoured the code with no luck.

I'm at a loss, no idea why the site persists in requesting HTTP stylesheets from Google.

Any ideas?

https://premiosolutions.com

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it looks like you want to use https with google and are currently using plain http: _Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.premiosolutions.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,600,300,700|Cinzel'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS._

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Yep, that is the error message. As I stated, if you look at the source code, you will see that there are only references to HTTPS or //script, which is how you avoid these errors. Or at least as far as my knowledge on the topic goes. There are no references in any of the code to HTTP when it comes to loading any google scripts.

Comment: You have one reference to "https://fonts.googleapis.com/" which results in a 404

Comment: Nevermind I think I found it. Your CSS file `https://www.premiosolutions.com/wp-content/plugins/client-carousel/classes/assets/css/client_css.css?ver=1.0.0` refers to `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,600,300,700|Cinzel);`

Comment: Damn man, you are incredible. Thank you so much! I wonder why my string search through the entire WP directory structure didn't return that reference. Either way, awesomeness.

Answer (score 0):

> Nevermind I think I found it. Your CSS file
>   https://www.premiosolutions.com/wp-content/plugins/client-ca‌​rousel/classes/asset‌​s/css/client_css.css‌​?ver=1.0.0
>   refers to @import
>   url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,‌​600,300,700|Cinzel);
>   – j08691

Problem solved. Pesky outdated plugin. Thanks @j08691